# Google word2vec load error

Tags: gpu, segmentation-fault, gensim, word2vec

I want to use Google word2vec (GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin) 
I downloaded it from https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/
When I load it, the memory errors occured 
(Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV))

```
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
embedding_path = "data/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin"
word2vec = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format(embedding_path, binary=True)
print word2vec
```

I use ubuntu 16.04 / GTX-1070(8gb) / Ram(16gb).
How can I fix it?!
 [image]
[image]

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace of the error?

Comment: @TheM00s3 I'm sorry but how can I get the full stacktrace of the error? Actually, I used Pycharm as a python ide. And the only error sentences are "Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)"

Comment: You can try and run it through terminal by calling commands like `python //myScript.py, then see if an error appears.

Comment: @TheM00s3 Thnk you for replying! When I run it on terminal , it just says " Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX 1070 (CNMeM is enabled with initial size: 80.0% of memory, cuDNN 5105)
Segmentation fault (core dumped) "

Comment: I think this is related to you using Cuda with word2vec. I'd go ahead and post this as an issue on Gensim's github page, its probably something to do with the implementation and using cuda.

Answer (score 0):

A SIGSEGV is an error occurring when the process tries to access a particular segment in memory that it does not have permission on.
So you should check permissions and, by debugging, see which memory location gives you the error.
This way you could understand if another program is interfering.
The problem might also be CUDA related as @TheM00s3 suggested